# Installing packages from Azure DevOps Artifact Feed in a Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have two repositories.

- The first is built by AzureDevOps Pipelines into a whl file and published on a Azure DevOps Artifact feed. (works)
- The second should also be built by AzureDevOps Pipelines and published on Azure DevOps artifacts -> but it  *is dependend on the first one and needs to install it from the AzureDevops Artifact feed during the build-process.* (this does not work).

I can install it locally, but the pipeline of the second package fails. When the pipeline fails, I get the following error:

```
401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: 
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<company>/<some-numbers>/_packaging/<some-numbers>/pypi/download/<mypackage>/0.0.1.9/<mypackage>-0.0.1.9-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=<some-numbers>
```

---------------------------------- SETUP ----------------------------------

I added the feed as a secondary source to the **pyproject.toml** of my second repository, this allows me to successfully install the first package with `poetry add <firstpackage>` and `poetry install` for my local IDE:

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "azure"
url = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<company>/<some-numbers>/_packaging/<feed-name>/pypi/simple/"
secondary = true
```

YAML script to **install packages** via poetry - **works for the first repository, but not for the second repository** which needs to install the first package from the Azure DevOps artifcats feed (the first installs everything from pypi.org):

```
- script: |
    python -m pip install -U pip
    pip install poetry==1.1.3  # Install poetry via pip to pin the version
    poetry install
  displayName: Install software
```

YAML script to **publish a package** to an Azure DevOps artifact feed (with a personal access token as authentification) - **works**:

```
- script: |
    poetry config repositories.azure https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<company>/<somenumbers>/_packaging/<feed-name>/pypi/upload/
    poetry config http-basic.azure usernamedoesnotmatter $(pat)
    poetry publish --repository azure
    exit 0
  displayName: Publish package
```

Comment: I think it is a potential security risk to submit your personal access token (PAT) in the `pyproject.toml` file.

Comment: You are completely right, I also removed the token from the file. It is also not necessary if poetry config is set up with ` poetry config http-basic.azure`. I edited the question so people in the future wont make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I just needed to configure poetry in the pipeline before the install for the second repository - same as I did locally, some long time ago (and forgot about it).

```
- script: |
    python -m pip install -U pip
    pip install poetry==1.1.3  # Install poetry via pip to pin the version
    
    # configuring the feed as a secondary source for poetry
    poetry config repositories.azure https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<company>/<some-numbers>/_packaging/<feed-name>/pypi/simple/
    poetry config http-basic.azure userNameDoesntMatter $(pat)  

    poetry install    
    displayName: Install software
```

Comment: Cribber did you specify the PAT somewhere? If I simply add our artifact feed link (https://ourorg.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/ourfeed/pypi/simple/), it doesn't find the package. In pyproject.toml it is specified to use that feed as well as an explicit alternative source (and that works locally, but not in Azure). Any ideas how to fix or even properly debug this?

Comment: `$(pat)` references a local variable defined in the UI of DevOps for the pipeline called `pat` which contains a personal access token which has read writes on the artifactory

Comment: Even if you would use the proposed solution in the post in this post, you should 'hide' the PAT in your pipeline variables. Else you introduce a security risk, your PAT is personal and should stay personal. The solution with the `$(System.AccessToken)` would be both more consice, easier to maintain, and gives less risks for security problems.

Answer (score 2):

I am not checking my Personal Access Token (PAT) into my repository.

pyproject.toml (partial):

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "azure"
url = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<company>/<some-numbers>/_packaging/<feed-name>/pypi/simple/"
secondary = true
```

I added the `PipAuthenticate@1` task that sets the `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` environment variable that contains a PAT. In the script, I extract the PAT and use it to configure poetry.

azure-pipelines.yaml (partial):

```
  - task: PipAuthenticate@1
    displayName: 'Pip Authenticate'
    inputs:
      artifactFeeds: '<some-numbers>/<feed-name>'
      onlyAddExtraIndex: True


  - script: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install poetry
      export PAT=$(echo "$PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL" | sed 's/.*build:\(.*\)@pkgs.*/\1/')
      poetry config http-basic.azure build "$PAT"
      poetry install
    displayName: "Install dependencies"
```

Comment: Azure DevOps also allows you to store a secret variable (e.g. the personal access token) along the pipeline which you can reference with `$(varname)`, this is easier than using the export command. 
I'm not sure why you install twine though?

Comment: @Cribber I removed the twine installation step. Use it for publishing the python package to Azure Artifacts, but not relevant in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution uses the predefined system variable `$(System.AccessToken)`. This variable is available in both **build** pipelines and **release** pipeline. [See link to azure documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken)

A detailed description (for *release*-pipelines) is set up in this [article](https://ranari.com/2020/03/31/personal-access-token-in-azure-pipelines/).

You can use it like this in the build pipeline yaml:

```
poetry config http-basic.azure userNameDoesntMatter $(System.AccessToken)
poetry install
```

The system access token is coming from the Azure DevOps system. However, it does require some additional setup: you need to **grant the "AddPackage" permission to the DevOps service principal** in order to enable him to publish to the feed. In the settings of the specific feed, go to the "permissions" tab and assign the role `Collaborator` to the service principal `<your_devops_workspace> Build Service (<your_Azure_DevOps_Account>)`.

An advantage of using the System token + giving the role to the SP, is that PATs require regular updates as they expire after a year at most.

Security wise, using a secured PAT as a pipeline variable is not less safe than using the SP, but it reduces complexity.

Comment: This might be possible for Azure Release Pipelines, but not for the **build-pipelines** that this post is about.

Comment: @Cribber have you tried this, or do you have a source for this? I have indeed tested this in the Azure Release Pipeline, but I do not read anywhere it's limited to this pipeline.

Comment: The script argument and configuration checkbox you reference in the detailed description article simply does not exist for yml based Build-Pipelines.

Comment: On a different note - it doesn't make a lot of sense to name your poetry config "http-basic.your_package" (=based your package name). The config variable is the name of the index, not the package that you install. People might want to install multiple packages from the same index, so this would get confusing.

Comment: You are right, this should have been `your_package_source` I updated this in the answer.

Comment: The detailed description is just illustrating how to use the `$(System.AccessToken)`, this is an example. I also don't use the script argument and the configuration checkbox. Only the `$(System.AccessToken)` in the yaml.

Comment: All I know is that the detailed description that you linked is a completely different setup/case. Furthermore, you said yourself that you haven't actually checked whether your proposed solution works for build-pipelines. Please check whether your solution actually works before posting an answer...

Comment: I tested it and fixed/edited the answer, also removed all unnecessary/wrong information.